# Using react-google-maps, map is hidden with position: relative

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs

Having some trouble with getting google maps to render using the api.
My HTML markup currently looks like:

```
<div className='container-fluid'>
  <div className='row full-height'>
    <div className='col-xs-6'>
      <GettingStartedGoogleMap
        containerElement={
          <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />
        }
        mapElement={
          <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />
        }
        onMapLoad={this.handleMapLoad}
        onMapClick={this.handleMapClick}
        markers={this.state.markers}
        onMarkerRightClick={this.handleMarkerRightClick}
      />
    </div>
    <div className='col-xs-6'>
       <h1>Browse All Properties</h1>
          {this.props.properties.map(function(property, i) {
             return (
               <a href={'housing_applications/' + property.id} key={i}>{property.name}</a>
             )
           })}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The strange thing is that when I inspect element, I see that there's a `position: relative` in [image: Inspected Element]

When I delete the `position: relative`, a sliver of the map is then viewable.  This seems out of my control though, and is a css property that is pulled in from the api.  Would like some suggestions on how to properly integrate google maps into react.

Comment: which is the map component you are using?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38202950/reactjs-google-maps-style-infowindow/38211839#38211839